# Can I have a laptop case separate from my carry on on Delta?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage, delta-air-lines

I have a laptop case that is pretty big, as it can fit my PlayStation 4, it’s games and my laptop. However it fills the majority of my carry on. I was wondering if I could have my laptop case separate from my carry on and just carry it onto the plane. Or if I should just keep it in my carry on. I am flying on Delta.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delta carry-on policy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/126225/delta-carry-on-policy)

Answer (score 12):

Delta allows [one "carry on bag" and one "personal item"](https://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/baggage/during-your-trip/carry-on.html) on board. The carry on bag is allowed to go in the overhead bins, while the personal item must fit under the seat in front of you. So it is perfectly fine to bring one carry on bag and your laptop case as a separate personal item, as long as the laptop case fits under the seat (I've never seen one that doesn't) and you don't have any other personal item (purse, briefcase, etc.).

Comment: Thank you so much. This’ll save me some space!

Comment: The vast majority of non-"el cheapo" airlines in the United States (and, I believe, in most western countries) have a broadly similar policy (but the precise size limits will vary, so look those up for your airline).

Comment: @MollyHunt Just so it's clear, if you carry a purse that counts as your personal item, so if you would normally carry a purse along with your usual carry-on bag, you'll need to put it in one of the other bags while boarding.